# Not able to launch administrative console from RAD. Error - administrative port not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-7, ibm-rad

I am getting this error while launching Admin console - "Cannot launch Administrative console since administrative port is not found".

I Tried launching console from explorer using http://localhost:9060/ibm/console/login.do. It is opening but when I click on application server under server->server type, getting following stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at           com.ibm.ws.console.servermanagement.applicationserver.ServerController.setupCollectionForm    (ServerController.java:582)
at com.ibm.ws.console.servermanagement.applicationserver.ServerController.perform(ServerController.java:354)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:242)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:308)
at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:207)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1486)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:510)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1449)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1384)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:927)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:494)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:315)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

Any pointers on how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after system restart it has solved the issue on its own.